# Difference between void foo(T y) and <T> void foo(T y) in Java generic class

Tags: java, generics, object-oriented-analysis

Explain in detail the difference, if any, between the following two versions of a Java generic class?

```
class C<T>{
    T x;
    void foo(T y)  { … }
}
```

and

```
class C<T>{
    T x;
    <T> void foo(T y)  { … }
}
```

and another question: What could be written in the body of foo(), replacing the “…” that would cause the Java compiler to accept the first version of C but reject the second version of C.

I'm very puzzled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class C<T>{
    T x;
    <T> void foo(T y)  { … }
}
```

is a confusing way to write

```
class C<T>{
    T x;
    <S> void foo(S y)  { … }
}
```

as for what would reject the second version, for example this:

```
class C<T>{
    T x;
    <T> void foo(T y)  { x = y; }
}
```

will fail, because if you rewrite it as

```
class C<T>{
    T x;
    <S> void foo(S y)  { x = y; }
}
```

you can immediately see that you're missing a cast (the exact compiler error is "incompatible types").

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the `T` type variable in the method `foo` represents the very same type that is declared in the class definition `C<T>`.

The second example is a pitfall, because the `T` in the method declaration is a completely different type unrelated to the type parameter of the class, it just happens to have the same name `T`. It is a similar case to the situation when a local variable hides a field of the same name.

Eclipse emits a nice compiler warning (if this warning is turned on in the settings, not sure if it is on by default) for this situation:

> The type parameter T is hiding the type T